# batch: complete and part of path in csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, copy

I have a csv file with three columns:
1: is a path to a file that has to be copied.
2: tells wether the file from 1 has to be copied.
3: gives the foldername of the target location the file from 1 has to be copied to.

"path"  /     Yes or No    /   "folder name"

What I have up until now:

```
for /F skip=1 "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a IN (C:\somewhere\sourcefile.csv) DO if %%b ==Yes GOTO copy "%%a" "%%c"

:COPY
copy /d /v "%%a" "C:\somwhereelse\%%c"
```

So first i want the for loop to start reading with the second line and put the content into %%a, %%b and %%c. If B is yes, the file which can be found under %%a should be copied to a path plus the folder which comes from %%c.

If that is done, or if %%b was NO, the for-loop should proceed with line 3, until there are no entries in the csv file anymore.

Please be aware, that this is my first batch and i am not too experienced in coding.

thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a IN (C:\somewhere\sourcefile.csv) DO (
    if /i "%%b"=="Yes" (
        set "file=%%~a"
        set "folder=%%~c"

)

if not defined file goto:eof
copy /d /v "%file%" "C:\somwhereelse\%folder%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use `call :COPY ...` instead of `goto COPY` here, otherwise the call won't return to the loop. You'd also have to use `%1` and `%2` instead of `%%a` and `%%c` in the called routine. And use `~` to remove enclosing double quotes from the variables, so you don't end up with nested double quotes.

```
@echo off
for /F skip=1 "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a IN (C:\somewhere\sourcefile.csv) DO (
  if "%%b"=="Yes" call :copy "%%~a" "%%~c"
)
goto :eof

:COPY
copy /d /v "%~1" "C:\somwhereelse\%~2"
```

However, it'd be a lot simpler to just use the `copy` command inside the loop:

```
@echo off
for /F skip=1 "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (C:\somewhere\sourcefile.csv) do (
  if "%%~b"=="Yes" copy /d /v "%%~a" "C:\somwhereelse\%%~c"
)
```